# force cmake FIND_LIBRARY to look in custom directory

Tags: cmake

cmake version 2.8.4

I have the following apache portable runtime libraries that I have compiled myself and want my application to link against.

My project directory where my apr libraries are:

```
gw_proj/tools/apr/libs
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I have the following:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(APRUTIL NAMES "aprutil-1"
  PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr/libs)
```

My problem is on a machine that already has the apache portable runtime already installed it will look for it in this folder:

```
/usr/lib
```

So will always ignore my custom path.

How can I force the `FIND_LIBRARY` to always look in my custom directory:

```
gw_proj/tools/apr/libs
```

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify the search order using one or more of `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`, `NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`
, `NO_CMAKE_PATH`, `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`, `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH`, `ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`, or`NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`.

From the docs for [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html):

> The default search order is designed to be most-specific to least-specific for common use cases. Projects may override the order by simply calling the command multiple times and using the NO_* options:

> ```
> find_library(<VAR> NAMES name PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
> find_library(<VAR> NAMES name)
> ```

> Once one of the calls succeeds the result variable will be set and stored in the cache so that no call will search again.

So in your case, you can do

```
FIND_LIBRARY(APRUTIL NAMES "aprutil-1"
  PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/apr/libs NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```