# How to tell cmake to look for Boost headers in a specified location?

Tags: cmake

I am using Boost libraries for my cmake C++ project:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
```

Which correctly sets the `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable to my local Boost installation `/usr/local/inlude`

After I installed `miniconda`, which has its own boost installation, my project now looks for boost headers in

```
/usr/share/miniconda3/include/boost
```

How do I tell `cmake` not too look for boost headers in miniconda directories and use `/usr/local/include` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two Boost library with a different version number, you can specify the Version Number in find_package cmd, like this:
`find_package(Boost 1.62.0 ...)`

In addtion, if `/usr/share/miniconda3/include/boost` is not in your cmake search path, you may need:
`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/share/miniconda3/include/boost)`

Comment: Actually I want  cmake NOT to look in /usr/share/miniconda3/include, I would like to remove it from cmake search path, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. For this issue, you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763328/force-cmake-find-library-to-look-in-custom-directory